# How to sync slider value with form placeholder passthrough?

Tags: javascript, html

Pardon as I am a newbie coder. I have a slider that outputs a value as I drag it and display it with a span tag

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5" class="slider1" id="myRange1">
</div>

<h4>Score: <span id="demo1"></span></h4>

<div class="login-box">
    <form action="https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/69kvuydqzi9bu" method="post" id="sheetdb-form">
        <div class="user-box">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter name of panel" name="data[Panel]" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="txtInput1">
        </div>
        <ul class="actions">
            <li><button type="submit">Submit Score</button></li>
    </ul>
    </form>
</div>
```

which is linked to javascript code

```js
var slider1 = document.getElementById("myRange1");
var output1 = document.getElementById("demo1");
var input1 = document.getElementById("txtInput1");
output1.innerText = slider1.value; // Display the default slider value
input1.value = slider1.value;   
// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
slider1.addEventListener("input1", function() {
const slider1Value = this.value;
output1.innerText = input1Value;
input.value = slider1Value;
});
slider1.oninput = function() {
output1.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

because I want to pass the output of the slider value to a form tag because I want to submit the value to a googlesheet using API

everything is working, however, whenever I drag the slider the value displayed on the form placeholder is not updating. I want to sync them and update in real-time. Is this possible? Am I missing anything obvious?

Please save me. Thanks!

Comment: I think that all those snippets should actually be inside one, for better perspective of the whole functionality

Comment: Sure, Let me edit the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was couple of mistakes, mostly in the naming of the variables, but the most important one is was inside your `eventListener`.

As you can [see](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), the first element inside `()` should be the *type* of the `event`, not the name of the variable. So I've put `change` ([see more info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)), instead of `input1`.

Other changes are mostly typing errors, as I've said.

```js
var slider1 = document.getElementById("myRange1");
var output1 = document.getElementById("demo1");
var input1 = document.getElementById("txtInput1");
output1.innerText = slider1.value; // Display the default slider value
input1.value = slider1.value;   
// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
slider1.addEventListener("change", function() {
const slider1Value = this.value;
output1.innerText = slider1Value;
input1.value = slider1Value;
});
slider1.oninput = function() {
output1.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5" class="slider1" id="myRange1">
</div>
<h4>Score: <span id="demo1"></span></h4>
<div class="login-box">
    <form action="https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/69kvuydqzi9bu" method="post" id="sheetdb-form">
        <div class="user-box">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter name of panel" name="data[Panel]" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="txtInput1">
        </div>
        <ul class="actions">
            <li><button type="submit">Submit Score</button></li>
    </ul>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me a lot but I also learned from it.